# AWS EC2 Amazon Linux 2 AMI Starting PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgresql-13, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

Have an AWS EC2 instance which is running Amazon Linux AMI 2.
Installed PostgreSQL using

```
 sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql13
```

**Now, how to start it and configure it?**

I can see
`Package postgresql-13.3-2.amzn2.0.1.aarch64 already installed...`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql13
```

installs **only the client**. This is **not server**. You still have to setup server separately apart from the client yourself.

Thus, to install `postgresql 13`, you have install the client (if you haven't done so yet). It is needed as Amazon Linux 2 will install matching server (v13), not default version 9.

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql13
```

and now install server (this should install v13, as it matches your client):

```
sudo yum install postgresql-server
```

now you enable it:

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

initialize it:

```
sudo /usr/bin/postgresql-setup --initdb
```

start it:

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

and finally check its status:

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

Comment: I am really sorry, I was on medical leave. I am really sorry.

Comment: @CRSardar Its OK. Happens:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command to start the installed service in AML-2

```
$ sudo systemctl start postgresql-13
$ sudo systemctl status postgresql-13
```

Now to configure the postgresql server you need to configure postgresql.conf file which you can find by

```
$ find / -name postgresql.conf
```

or you can ask postgresql where is postgresql.conf

```
$ psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'
```

you can begin with [postgresql configurations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config.html)

also refer [install pg13 on amzl-2](https://techviewleo.com/install-postgresql-13-on-amazon-linux/) and validate your installation

Comment: Hi Nikhil, thanks for reply, but those are not working, getting - 
"sudo systemctl start postgresql-13" is giving error 


"Failed to start postgresql-13.service: Unit not found."